# Rotate JQuery Buttons to -45 Degrees without Space

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, button, rotation

I try to figure out, if it is possible to rotate a button group to -45 degrees. I have made an example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bubezonala/1/edit?html,css,output). My problem is the space between the rotated buttons. Any Idea how to group them together?

[image: buttongroup]

Comment: Not possible using CSS alone. You'll need some JS to calculate each button width and than apply some negative margin to your elements

Answer (score 0):

**How's [this](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaSpyder/7xwdwnh8/10/)?**

I kept everything the same except your CSS code:

```
.rotate {
  margin: 20px -33px 20px 0 !important;
  height: 24px !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
```

Styles from the jQuery UI sheet were automatically setting a margin on your buttons, so I added a margin of -33 on the right of each button. I had to override the jQuery UI styles with `!important`. The buttons would come apart again if factors such as the font-size of the buttons was changed, so I used `height: 24px !important` to override that.

Comment: thx - nice one, but it is floating not so smoothly together, also when you use margin-right: -33px !important; (which is for me the best viewing). Your can see, that the lining is sometimes not perfectly.

Comment: Hm, you're right. It is a few pixels off. I couldn't find another jQuery UI style that would be causing the buttons to be different sizes though. I think it must have to do with the text within the buttons - if you change the "Mathe" text, etc., you'll see the buttons render at different sizes. :(